# Teradata SP specify which result set

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, teradata

If I create a Stored Procedure in Teradata with multiple dynamic result sets is there a way to specify which to return in the CALL()?

For example, if I want to call the procedure from an SSRS report with multiple sections. My initial thought is to pass a variable and use an IF to set the return set.

Comment: As far as I know, SSRS will only consume the first result set from a stored procedure, and just happily ignore the others.  If the result sets have the same structure, you could union them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial thought is correct, you determine which result set(s) are returned by doing an `OPEN cursor`. If you don't `OPEN` it (or `CLOSE` it again) it will not be returned.